# Installing Flocker on Ubuntu 14.0.4.1 server

Tags: command-line

I am installing `flocker-cli` and dependencies inside the `virtualenv` and also upgrading the pip Python package manager to its latest version inside the `virtualenv`. I am getting some error.

**Error Message:**

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sh linux-install.sh

Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in flocker-tutorial/bin/python2.7
Not overwriting existing python script flocker-tutorial/bin/python (you must use flocker-tutorial/bin/python2.7)
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in ./flocker-tutor ial/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in ./flocker-tutorial/lib/python2.7/site-p ackages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/administrator/.pip/pip.log
Installing Flocker and dependencies, this may take a few minutes with no output to the terminal...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl e=self.bundle)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files do_download,
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url self.session,
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 395, in get return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/p ip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/administrator/flocker-tutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /archive.clusterhq.com/downloads/flocker/Flocker-0 .2.1-py2-none-any.whl (Caused by : [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)
Storing debug log for failure in /home/administrator/.pip/pip.log
```

What do I have to do to resolve this error?

Thanks,
Radha S

Comment: The error says `ConnectionError ... (Caused by : [Errno 101] Network is unreachable)`. Can the machine access the internet? Can it reach `storage.googleapis.com`?

Comment: The machine access the URL with http but failing to access the URL with https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your computer and/or your network so that you can establish https-connections.

PIP can't access https://storage.googleapis.com and https://pypi.python.org/simple/ . And thus pip can't install anything.

There are many possibilities why this is the case. It has most probably something to do with your network configuration. Either on your computer or on the network/firewall/gateway.